# TSQL Group by Column with Multiple Values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQLServer 2008r2 as below.

[image: example dataset]

I want to select all the records where the `[Fg]` column = 1 that consecutively by `[Id]` order lead into value 2 for each `[T_Id]` and `[N_Id]` combination.

There can be instances where record prior to `[Fg]` = 2 doesn't = 1

There can be any number of records where the value of `[Fg]` = 1 but only one record where `[Fg]` = 2 for each `[T_Id]` and `[N_Id]` combination.

So for the example below, I want to select records with `[Id]`s (4,5) and (7,8,9 )and (19,20).

Any records for `[T_Id]` 3 and 4 are excluded.

**Expected output**

[image: Expected output]

Example data set

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE ( Id INT IDENTITY (1,1), T_Id INT, N_Id INT, Fg TINYINT )

INSERT INTO @Data
(T_Id, N_Id, Fg)
VALUES
(1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 3, 0), (2, 3, 1), 
(2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (3, 4, 0), (3, 4, 0), (3, 4, 0), (3, 4, 2), (4, 5, 0), 
(4, 5, 1), (4, 5, 0), (4, 5, 2), (5, 7, 0), (5, 7, 1), (5, 7, 2)
```

Comment: so, all records with FG 0 have to be filtered? Because otherwise 0, 1, 2 would be a correct order of consecuting records, no? And why is ID 7 expected as correct record since ID 7 and 8 both have FG 1?

Comment: @Tyron78 you can have multiple consecutive records where the FG = 1. I explained this in the question

Comment: Look als [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2/); why using SQLServer 2008r2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can be done easily using `recursive CTE`:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT DS1.*
    FROM @Data DS1
    INNER JOIN @Data DS2
        ON DS1.[T_Id] = DS2.[T_Id]
        AND DS1.[N_Id] = DS2.[N_Id]
        AND DS1.[Id] = DS2.[Id] + 1
        AND DS1.[Fg] = 2
        AND DS2.[Fg] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DS1.*
    FROM @Data DS1
    INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
        ON DS1.[T_Id] = DS2.[T_Id]
        AND DS1.[N_Id] = DS2.[N_Id]
        AND DS1.[Id] = DS2.[Id] - 1
        AND DS1.[Fg] = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
ORDER BY Id
```

[image]

The idea is simple. The first part of the query gets all `valid` records with `fg = 2` - valid means there is record before this one with `fg = 1` from the same group.

Then in the recursive part we are getting all records smaller then initial ones, that has `fg = 1`.

Comment: @gotqn Thank for this.  I was messing around for a long time with a `CROSS APPLY` solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use lag/lead because it started in SQL 2012, you will need to do something like the below.

```
SELECT  fg - (
        SELECT  TOP 1 fg
        FROM    table m2
        WHERE   m2.fg = m1.fg-1 OR (m2.fg = m1.fg AND m2.id < m1.id)
        ORDER BY 
                fg, id
        )
FROM table m1
ORDER BY
      fg, id
```